# error al convertir objeto a svf en Autodesk Forge

Tags: aforge

Estoy intentando crear un visor básico con atodesk forge siguiendo los pasos del tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-viewer/

En cierto punto, se pide transformar el archivo en SVF:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/
Cuando hago a petición con los datos requeridos se me devuelve un HTML de error que dice que la pagina a la que intento acceder no está disponible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
        <style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>An error occurred.</h1>
        <p>Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
            <br/>
Please try again later.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

He intentado cambiar la urn (otra diferente y otra sin transformar) pero aun así no funciona
Me gustaría saber si alguien sabe como se puede solucionar o si Autodesk sigue dando soporte a este servicio
gracias :)

Comment: Estas en SO en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta o va a terminar cerrada

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En ésta web está mejor explicado.

https://learnforge.autodesk.io

yo empecé por ahí, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Aunque esto teoricamente solucione la pregunta, [seria preferible](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) que incluyas las partes esenciales en la respuesta aqui, y dejes el link solo como referencia.